# Filter method and that objects are passed by ref

Tags: javascript

How can I do the below without changing the "list" variable? As far as I can understand from the docs (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the filter method should return a New variable but the below says to me that it is just a reference since the "list" variable changes?
Can someone explain this behavior and how to go around it (do not want to change the original "list" var)?

```js
    var list = [{topic : "fussball", arr : [1,2]}, {topic : "soccer", arr : [3,4]}, 
                {topic : "fussball", arr : [5,6]},{topic : "soccer", arr : [7,8]}];
    function someFilterMethod(list, topic){
      let tops = list.filter( function(obj){ 
      if(obj.topic == topic){
        return obj;}  
      });
      for(let i = 0; i < tops.length ; i++){
        if(i < (tops.length)) {
          for(let j = (i+1) ; j<tops.length ; j++){
            if( tops[i].topic.trim() == tops[j].topic.trim() ){
              tops[i].arr.push.apply(tops[i].arr, tops[j].arr);
              tops.splice(j, 1);
            }
         }
       }
     }
     return tops;
    }

    var a = someFilterMethod(list, "fussball");
    console.log(a);
    //> Array [Object { topic: "fussball", arr: Array [1, 2, 5, 6] }]
    console.log(list);
    //> Array [Object { topic: "fussball", arr: Array [1, 2, 5, 6] }, Object { topic: "soccer", arr: Array [3, 4] }, Object { topic: "fussball", arr: Array [5, 6] }, Object { topic: "soccer", arr: Array [7, 8] }, Object { topic: "hockey", arr: Array [9, 10] }, Object { topic: "golf", arr: Array [11, 12] }, Object { topic: "hockey", arr: Array [13, 14] }, Object { topic: "golf", arr: Array [15, 16] }]
```

The someFilterMethod just takes the elements of the same "topic", concatenates their arrays and returns that.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? clearly mention your expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to parse and strigify json, otherwise it will modify the existing object

```js
var list = [{topic : "fussball", arr : [1,2]}, {topic : "soccer", arr : [3,4]}, 
            {topic : "fussball", arr : [5,6]},{topic : "soccer", arr : [7,8]}];
function someFilterMethod(list, topic){
  let tops = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(list)).filter( function(obj){ 
  if(obj.topic == topic){
    return obj;}  
  });
  for(let i = 0; i < tops.length ; i++){
    if(i < (tops.length)) {
      for(let j = (i+1) ; j<tops.length ; j++){
        if( tops[i].topic.trim() == tops[j].topic.trim() ){
          tops[i].arr.push.apply(tops[i].arr, tops[j].arr);
          tops.splice(j, 1);
        }
     }
   }
 }
 return tops;
}

var a = someFilterMethod(list, "fussball");
console.log(a);
//> Array [Object { topic: "fussball", arr: Array [1, 2, 5, 6] }]
console.log(list);
//> Array [Object { topic: "fussball", arr: Array [1, 2, 5, 6] }, Object { topic: "soccer", arr: Array [3, 4] }, Object { topic: "fussball", arr: Array [5, 6] }, Object { topic: "soccer", arr: Array [7, 8] }, Object { topic: "hockey", arr: Array [9, 10] }, Object { topic: "golf", arr: Array [11, 12] }, Object { topic: "hockey", arr: Array [13, 14] }, Object { topic: "golf", arr: Array [15, 16] }]
```

Comment: Thanks!! @Akhil Why is that? Does it create a new object and drops the ref?

Comment: thats sought of object property, 'reference' like that.:D; if you think my answer is correct please mark it as correct, take care buddy.

Answer (score 1):

With Array.filters, new reference for the Array is created, however, objects continue to share the same reference. Hence, any change in objects of the filtered array will mean a change in original array.

You can try following

```js
 var list = [{topic : "fussball", arr : [1,2]}, {topic : "soccer", arr : [3,4]}, {topic : "fussball", arr : [5,6]},{topic : "soccer", arr : [7,8]}];
 
    function someFilterMethod(list, topic){
      return list.reduce((a,c) => {
        if(c.topic == topic) a.arr = [...a.arr, ...c.arr];
        return a;
      }, {topic, arr: []});
    }

    var a = someFilterMethod(list, "fussball");
    console.log(a);
    console.log(list);
```